# How to filters two arrays with multiple keys and value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var filteredKeyItems = ['primary','gender','regular','normal']
var filteredValuesItems = ['genreal','M',true]

// Output should be:

filteredKeyItems = ['primary','gender']
filteredValuesItems = ['genreal','M']
```

Here there is a snippet of the two arrays with the keys and values.
How can I filter multiple keys as denoted into the code regular and normal with values true in values arrays.
Final output should be as per the denoted into the snippet.

Thanks.

Comment: `two arrays with the keys and values`. I do not see any key or value. Secondly no way able to find logic of the output

Comment: keys = 'regular' , 'normal'
values = true

Comment: Hello Sachin, is not very clear what do you want to do, you dont have key/value pairs (even if in you program behave like that), you have arrays, so maybe your question should be edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Its very clear that 
keys are normal and regular and
values is true

So I want to filter regular=true and normal=true and filtered two arrays

Comment: How did you get keys into one array and values into another array? Maybe you could modify that code to send out key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty functional way is:

```js
var filteredKeyItems = ['primary','gender','regular','normal']
var filteredValuesItems = ['genreal','M',true]

function filterKeyItem(keyItem) {
    return keyItem !== 'regular' && keyItem !== 'normal';
}

filteredValuesItems = filteredValuesItems.filter((valueItem, index) => filterKeyItem(filteredKeyItems[index]));
filteredKeyItems = filteredKeyItems.filter(filterKeyItem);

console.log('filteredKeyItems', filteredKeyItems);
console.log('filteredValuesItems', filteredValuesItems);
```

To improve performance a bit, you can use a simple `for` loop with filling result arrays.

Answer (score 1):

we can do this also by follow

```js
    var filteredKeyItems = ['primary','gender','regular','normal']
    var filteredValuesItems = ['genreal','M',true]


    let filterTwo=[]
    let filterOne=filteredKeyItems.filter((element,index)=>{
     
      //we can assign condition here
    if(element=="primary" || element=="gender" ){
       filterTwo.push(filteredValuesItems[index])
      return  element}}  )
   
    console.log(filterOne)
    console.log(filterTwo)
```